# Tildes en el codigo de huffman

Tags: java

Tengo este código para calcular el código de huffman, pero al ingresar algún texto que tenga tildes o la ñ en lugar de salir ese caracter salen caracteres tipo Ã, lo intente con este texto:
Todavía tengo casi todos mis dientes

casi todos mis cabellos y poquísimas canas

puedo hacer y deshacer el amor

trepar una escalera de dos en dos

y correr cuarenta metros detrás del ómnibus

o sea que no debería sentirme viejo

pero el grave problema es que antes

no me fijaba en estos detalles.

Un poema hermoso de Mario Benedetti, me gusto mucho niño.

y esta fue la salida:
{B=00111100, Ã=011100, M=00111011, T=00111101, U=00111010,  =110, ¡=00111110, a=1011, b=011000, c=01101, d=0001, e=100, f=01100100, g=001100, h=001101, i=10100, j=01111011, ,=00111111, l=01000, ­=0111011, m=10101, n=0000, .=0011100, o=1111, p=011111, ±=01100101, q=0111100, r=0101, ³=01111010, s=1110, t=0010, u=01001, v=0110011, y=0111010}

sabrían como solucionarlo? gracias de antemano.

````
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

class Node implements Comparable<Node>{
    char ch;
    int frequency;
    Node left;
    Node right;
    boolean leaf = false;
    String encoded="";
    Node(int frequency){
        this.frequency = frequency;
        this.leaf = false;
    }
    Node(char ch, int frequency){
        this.ch = ch;
        this.frequency = frequency;
        this.leaf = true;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node n){
        return this.frequency-n.frequency;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "("+ch+": "+frequency+"- "+encoded+")";
    }
}

class HuffmanTree{
    //Atributos y constructor
    Node root;
    char characters[];
    int frequency[];
    Map<Character,String> current = new HashMap<Character,String>();
    HuffmanTree()  {
        super();
    }
    //Huffman tree building
    public void HuffmanTreeBuilding(String file) throws FileNotFoundException{
        try {
            Scanner f = new Scanner(new java.io.File(file));
            Map<Character,Integer> ht = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
            while(f.hasNextLine()){
                String data = f.nextLine();
                for(int i=0;i<data.length();i++){
                    if(!ht.containsKey(data.charAt(i))){
                        ht.put(data.charAt(i),0);
                    }
                    ht.put(data.charAt(i),ht.get(data.charAt(i))+1);
                }
            }
            Set<Character> keys = ht.keySet();
            characters = new char[keys.size()];
            frequency = new int[keys.size()];
            int i=0;
            for(char x : keys){
                characters[i] = x;
                frequency[i] = ht.get(characters[i]);
                i++;
            } 
            PriorityQueue<Node> heap = new PriorityQueue<Node>();
            for(int j=0;j<characters.length;j++){
                heap.add(new Node(characters[j],frequency[j]));
            }
            while(heap.size()!=1){
                Node left  = heap.remove();
                Node right = heap.remove();
                Node newNode = new Node(left.frequency+right.frequency);
                newNode.left = left;
                newNode.right = right;
                root = newNode;
                heap.add(newNode);
            }
            Encode(root,"");
            System.out.println(current);
        }catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Error leyendo el archivo");
        }
    }
    void Encode(Node node, String genEncode){
        if(node.leaf){
            node.encoded = genEncode;
            current.put(node.ch,genEncode);
            return;
        }
        Encode(node.left,genEncode+"0");
        Encode(node.right,genEncode+"1");
    }  
}

public class Huffman{
    
    public static void main(String args[])throws java.io.FileNotFoundException{
        try {
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in
            System.out.println("Ingrese la ubicacion del archivo: ");
            String n = reader.next();// Scans the next token of the input as an int.
            //once finished
            reader.close();
            String file = n;
            HuffmanTree tree = new HuffmanTree();
            tree.HuffmanTreeBuilding(file);
        }catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Error 404 file not found");
        }
    }
} ```
````

Comment: Hola ¿En qué Sistema Operativo lo ejecutas amigo?

Comment: ¿lo estas ejecutando con MS-Dos? es que desde Netbeans y desde linux se ejecuta correctamente. Pudiera ser también el editor de texto con que se genero el archivo pues al menos copiando tal cual el código no se genera problema alguno.